# Find and replace in Javascript, unless already inplace

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to premise this with the fact that I am super new to JS.

I'm looking to do a find and replace with JS. The twist is that I want the find and replace do not change anything if the result is already in place (if that makes any sense?)

My example is that I want run the JS to add a "®" a word, but not to add it if the symbol is already present.

Thanks a lot for your help,
Harry

```
$("body").children().each(function () {
    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/Hello/g,"Hello®") );
});
```

Comment: Java has NOTHING to do with JavaScript

Comment: You can use regexs for finding various patterns within a text. I think finding words that do not end with specific symbol would work for you case. Try searching for "regex not ending with"

Comment: Maybe `/Hello®?/g` Not a fan of replacing huge amounts of HTML because of what it could break.

Comment: Already present where? After current word or in general in current string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if "®" already available or not using `$(this).html().indexOf("®") === -1` and if this condition return true then replace.

```
$("body").children().each(function () {
    if($(this).html().indexOf("®") === -1) {
      $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/Hello/g,"Hello®") );
    }
});
```

Comment: What if it is `Foo® Hello`?  ;) Edge case.

Comment: Is this the case?

Comment: Not sure why, but it doesn't seem to be working for my situation. Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: can you please add your html too?

Comment: Thanks Vivek.

Made this change and it seems to work.

$("body :not(script)").children().each(function () {
    if($(this).html().indexOf("®") === -1) {
      $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/Hello/g,"Hello®") );
    }
});

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: If my answer helps you than please accept my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using regex `/(^|\s)Hello(\s|$)/g`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello®</p>
</body>
<script>
  $("body").children().each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/(^|\s)Hello(\s|$)/g, "Hello®"));
  });
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend working with Regular Expressions until you've uncovered a pattern that eliminates "matches" where the symbol already exists. Also, don't forget to check for the various entities, such as `&reg;`, that are used for this symbol.

There are some great regular expression testers out there. I recommend [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/)